# modify interface key using generic value

Tags: typescript

I am trying to generate a type using a value provided by a generic. Here is my attempt that doesn't compile

```
type modifyKey<T extends 'a' | 'b'> = {
    [id: `${T}changed`]: T | string;
    another: number
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
type modifyKey<T extends 'a' | 'b'> = {
  [Prop in T as `${T}changed`]: T | string;
} & {
   another: number
}

// type Result = { achanged: string;   bchanged: string; another: number; }
type Result = modifyKey<'a' | 'b'>
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#key-remapping-in-mapped-types) you can find docs for property renaming

P.S. According to convention, type name should be capitalized